# How can I make a column to be in timestamp?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

How can I make this into a regular timestamp in Snowflake?

```
2019-09-15T21:43:02.000+0000
```

When I do this query:

```
select CREATEDDATE::TIMESTAMP FROM TBL1
```

I get an error:

> Timestamp '2019-09-15T21:43:02.000+0000' is not recognized

I would like the results to be:

```
2019-09-15 21:43:02.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly run a `to_timestamp` or variation of it, and tell Snowflake the format of the string that you are providing:

```
select to_timestamp('2019-09-15T21:43:02.000+0000','YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.FF3+TZHTZM');
```

If your `CREATEDDATE` is consistently like the example you provided, this should work.